# can I access api gate-way of a lambda and extend it?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have a lambda function like this :

```
 my_executor = python_lambda.PythonFunction(
        scope=self,
        id="my-lambda-new",
        runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
        role=existing_role_for_lambda,
        memory_size=512,
        function_name="my-lambda-new",
        description="This ",
        entry="./logs/src/myfolder",
        index='controller.py',
        handler="lambda_handler",
        timeout=core.Duration.minutes(5)        
   )
```

I have create api gate way like this :

```
 my_api = _apigateway.LambdaRestApi(
            scope=self,
            id="my-api",
            endpoint_configuration=_apigateway.EndpointConfiguration(
                types=[_apigateway.EndpointType.EDGE]
            ),
            handler=my_executor,
            default_cors_preflight_options=shared_stack.cors_options,
            deploy_options=api_stage,
            proxy=True
        )
```

and now In **other file** using lambda arn I am accessing lambda like this:

```
_lambda_arn = ssm.StringParameter.value_for_string_parameter(self, "my-executor-lambda-arn")
        self.my_executor_lambda = _lambda.Function.from_function_arn(self, "my_executor",
                                                                               _lambda_arn)
```

Now how I can extent it's api gateway . want to add new api end point in here

Answer (score 0):

from CDK docs:

> Import an existing RestApi that can be configured with additional Methods and Resources.

Take a look at [fromRestApiAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.RestApi.html#static-fromwbrrestwbrapiwbrattributesscope-id-attrs)

Comment: get this issue by using this  https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/20086